# Laravel route not found with angularjs route

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I am trying to concatenate Laravel route and angular route in href like this:

```
<a  href="./home/#/orders">Orders</a>
```

It shows correct url when I hover the link:

```
localhost/myproject/home/#/orders
```

But when I click on the link it redirects me to the following:

```
localhost/home/#/orders
```

It removes the project name from the link.

Here is laravel route:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Frontend'], function(){
        Route::get('/home', 'IndexController@home1');
});
```

And angular route:

```
.when('/orders', {
      templateUrl: './resources/views/Order/orders.html',
      controller: 'OrderController'
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Please guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<a  href="{{URL::to('home/#/orders')}}">Orders</a>
```

URL::to genreat the root url like http://localhost/yourproject/

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by removing '/' after home like this:

```
href="./home#/orders"
```